# Flash AS3 Remove Clip, reorder other items

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a scrollpane to which I add movieclips to. I am using it a an online users list. It works well so far but now I have run into a problem. I am able to remove the movieclips I want easily enough using removechild, but when I remove it there is only a blank space where the removed clip was. So I need to know how to have the scrollpane refresh somehow and move the clips below that one removed up. How can I do this?

I have tried invalidate, refreshPane, update, etc. Maybe I didnt have them in the correct order or something, but how can this be done?

If the answer is complex, could an example be provided please? Im really not good enough with as3 just yet to code an entire algorithm to get the number of children, remove them all, readding them, etc.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a variation, but saves the -1, simply rearrange such as:

```
lstOnline.removeChild(lstOnline.getChildByName("NAMEHERE"));

var numleft:Number = lstOnline.numChildren;
for(var i = 0; i < numleft - 1; i++) {
    lstOnline.getChildAt(i).y = i*60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I was a little better than I thought. In case anyone else faces this problem, the solution I found was the following:

```
var numleft:Number = lstOnline.numChildren;
    lstOnline.removeChild(lstOnline.getChildByName("NAMEHERE"));
    for(var i = 0; i < numleft - 1; i++) {
        lstOnline.getChildAt(i).y = i*60;
    }
```

lstOnline is the name of the ScrollPane and in my case 60 is the height of the added movieclips.

Comment: Just a tip about the i*60, this is a "magic number" you should create a variable to hold that value and use the variable instead, these things are a maintenance nightmare.